# nginx fresh install not serving pages from my chosen site document root

Tags: docker, nginx, synology

nginx fresh install not serving pages from my chosen site document root

I have a fresh install of nginx running in a docker container on a synology nas. Which is running fine, My nginx.conf file is:

```
server{
listen 5088 default_server;

root /www/public;
index index.html index.htm;
}
```

If I load 192.168.1.x:5088 in my browser I get nginx "403 forbidden" error. It seems to be trying to serve from the base dir of www and not the "public" folder.
Using the browser and navigating to 192.168.1.x/public the expected page loads...
I've tried changing where the nginx.conf file is mapped to in my composer script.  However neither seem to work.

- /volume1/docker/kitchenstock/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf # default directory
- /volume1/docker/kitchenstock/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

I'm new to nginx, any idea what's going on here?